# how to use foreach to get multiple fields into table

Tags: php, database, drupal, foreach

How can I use the foreach loop to get the values for each field (brand_id & brand_name) and have them inserted into the table 'pa_list_brands'?

if I use this code:

```
  $query = db_insert('pa_list_brands')->fields(array('brand_id', 'brand_name'));
  foreach ($data as $record) {
    $query->values($record);
  }
  $query->execute();
```

I get the ERROR:
"Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to InsertQuery::values() must be an array, string given"

So I tried this code to see what was being returned with $record:

```
 $query = db_insert('pa_list_brands')->fields(array('brand_id', 'brand_name'));
  foreach ($data as $record) {
    print_r($record);
  }
  $query->execute();
```

And I get ARRAY RESULT:

```
11Array
(
    [0] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [brand_id] =&gt; 1
            [brand_name] =&gt; Gildan
        )

    [1] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [brand_id] =&gt; 2
            [brand_name] =&gt; American Apparel
        )

    [2] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [brand_id] =&gt; 3
            [brand_name] =&gt; Rabbit Skins
        )

    [3] =&gt; stdClass Object
        (
            [brand_id] =&gt; 4
            [brand_name] =&gt; Anvil
        )
)
```

Thank you,
Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this below code.Below codes assign data as an array to "values" function for $query object class.

```
$query = db_insert('pa_list_brands')->fields(array('brand_id','brand_name'));

foreach ($data as $key=>$record) {

   $values[] = $record->brand_id;
   $values[] = $record->brand_name;
   $query->values($values);
   $values=null;
}
$query->execute();
```

Let me know if anything.

If link provided in my comment doesn't helps then try this below code.
You need to convert your object into array for "values" function to be work.

```
function objToArray($obj) {
    if(!is_array($obj) && !is_object($obj)) 
        return $obj;
    if(is_object($obj)) 
        $obj = get_object_vars($obj);
    return 
        array_map(__FUNCTION__, $obj);
}
$resultarr=objToArray($data);
if(is_array($resultarr))
  $resultarr=$resultarr[0];

 $query = db_insert('pa_list_brands')->fields(array('brand_id', 'brand_name'));
 foreach ($resultarr as $record) {
   $query->values($record);
 }
 $query->execute();
```

Comment: I used the code you provided and did receive and error
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in "the module" on line 48, Here is the line that cause the error: `$values[] = $record->brand_name; $query->values($values);` But it is weird that this line didn't cause an error: `$values[] = $record->brand_id;`

Comment: Please check this link.https://www.drupal.org/node/310079. Read the section "Inserting based on the results of a select query" in the given link which might be very useful to you.Thanks

Comment: Please mark an answer to correct if you are satisfied.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that worked:

```
$data = json_decode($data);
$data = $data->results;

  $query = db_insert('pa_list_brands')->fields(array('brand_id', 'brand_name'));
  foreach ($data as $key => $record) {
    $values[] = $record->brand_id;
    $values[] = $record->brand_name;
    $query->values($values);
    $values=null;
  }
  $query->execute();
```

Thank you @Jitesh for all of your help and insightful thoughts! I could not have done this without you.